# What alternatives are there for Boolean: Union

Tags: modifiers

Simple question, the Boolean operator causes a lot of problems for me when I merge two or more objects together. What alternatives are there to merge the meshes of two objects to form 1 solid merge? Paid alternatives are acceptable answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Bool Tool]
One tool I've run into is the Bool Tool, it's similar but it can get better results. You'll need to enable it in the user preferences to use it.