# How to cut plane with other object

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I would like to close of a model that I cut down using a boolean modifier so it is watertight, which is important for a different programm.

Although the images don't show it, the entire car is selected not only the intersecting edges that you can see in the top image.

The **main problem** is that I can't figure out how to split a plane into faces with a different, complex object. Also I need to be able to script everything so selecting vertices by hand for example isn't an option

[image]

So far I've:
Added thickness to the plane
Used the addon rob recommended isntead of the default boolean modifier
Deleted only the faces of the plane
Use the grid that results as a knife project onto a plane

The current problem is how I can only select the outer vertices instead of all, which would then be used in the knife project.

[image]

Comment: I have not tried it but there is an alternative Bool Tool built in, you just need to enable it. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109510/4937

Comment: @rob The results of the tool are much better